# How to run multiple Maven goals before launching Tomcat in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In the run configuration for Tomcat Server in IntelliJ you can specify Run Maven Goal, but you can't select multiple goals. I want to run several goals all as the same java process so that they can share properties generated by one of the goals. Specifically the ${changeSet} property created by the [build number maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/hgchangeset-mojo.html). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This feature is already implemented and will be available in the next IDEA update:

[image: new UI]

Such UI allows any number of custom tasks to be run in user specified order, including Maven goals.

Another solution would be to use something like [Mojo Executor](https://github.com/TimMoore/mojo-executor).

Comment: @JensKohl, it is available only in IDEA 12 EAP: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP. It will not be available in IDEA 11.x versions.